# Firing middleware body only in some cases

Tags: node.js, express

My understanding on express middleware has always been that it fires everytime when we put it in an express router. I was looking at the documentataion of express-bouncer npm package and I saw this:

```
bouncer.blocked = function (req, res, next, remaining)
{
    res.send (429, "Too many requests have been made, " +
        "please wait " + remaining / 1000 + " seconds");
};

// Route we wish to protect with bouncer middleware
app.post ("/login", bouncer.block, function (req, res)
{
    if (LoginFailed)
    {
        // Login failed
    }

    else
    {
        bouncer.reset (req);
        // Login succeeded
    }
});
```

What is stopping the `res.send` from firing every single time rather than just when there is a brute force attack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just overlooked the code, the function you defined is *blocked* and the middleware is *block* . You can see [in the source code](https://github.com/dkrutsko/express-bouncer/blob/master/bouncer.js#L118) that `block` contains the implementation to do the counting, and it only called `blocked` when the limitation is hit.